# Liste type in python some clarifications

Tags: python

I have this code :

```
if( capabilities is None ):
    capabilities = get_capabilities_specific(region=region,param=param,logger=logger)

logger.error("Capabilities type : %s", type(capabilities))
if( "Z_PT" in capabilities[-1] ):
```

The log is :

```
Capabilities type : <type 'list'>
```

The error is :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Exist a way to check if capabilities[-1] exist ? `And why check for capabilitites[-1]` ? Thx in advance. I'm new in python.

Comment: Simply check `if capabilities` to check if it is empty

Comment: What's the logic of `capabilitites[-1]` ?

Comment: it gets the last item of the list